# Is it possible to push data from the server to the client (phone, computer) without OS integration

Tags: networking, cloud, network-protocols

is there a way for a server to push some data to a client, wirelessly and seamlessly, which may be Windows(Phone), iPhone, Mac, or Android device, without any OS integration?

If so, what's the best design pattern to do this, and what are the best technologies to go about this?

Comment: Would the client be an app running on each of the devices?

Comment: I'd like to think that the client is a background process doing some magic behind the scenes.

Comment: In that case you would absolutely have some level of OS integration. If, for example, this were a webapp you could get away with not dealing with each individual OS.

Answer (score 1):

[Push technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology) is simply a methodology of the server initiating the transfer of data, rather than the client *asking* the server for it.

Apple makes push technology relatively easy to use by providing such functionality built-in on the OS. As well as Android through the [Google Cloud Messaging for Android](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html). Windows, however, does not.

Apple push notifications and Google's messaging for Android is seemingly magical and/or functionality that the OS needs to handle; however, this isn't necessarily the case. The advantage of having it "integrated" in the OS, is the same as having a framework handle the functionality for you.

---

Speaking in technical terms, push technology is a long-lived connection from the client to the server that accepts *messages*. These messages would be considered *pushed messages*, since the client did **not** make an individual request for them.

The main thing to keep in mind when implementing push technology yourself, is that the client **is** in charge of keeping that long-lived connection alive as much as possible. Because client IP addresses can change between disconnects, servers are not guaranteed that a client's address will be persistent across disconnects. Moreover, clients can be connected from behind a firewall, making it impossible for a server to reach the client.

For comparison, [pull technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pull_technology) is the more traditional process of a client connecting to a server and requesting data.

---

Your best bet for Apple iOS will be using their [push notification service](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html).

For Android devices you should use the [Google Cloud Messaging for Android](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html). Alternatively, you can create your own background service to handle the messaging; here's a [guide](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/60.html).

For Windows (*desktop at least*), you **will** have to create your own service to perform such duty. Here's an [MSDN guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a.aspx) explaining how to create a Windows Service using Visual Studio (*VB and C#*). There might be frameworks already built that handle such messaging on Windows, however, I don't know of any.

Comment: Jesse, thanks for the explanation! But I want to interact with the file system, or at least with multiple apps at the same time. This checks off Apple's APN. Any other idea?

Comment: @Devfly could you please expand a bit more? Your original question doesn't mention the file system.

Comment: @Devfly: I think you should add more info in your question. As example you have mentioned "file system" in the comment. However, it's absolutely not obvious from your question, because your write "some data".

Answer (score 1):

If by "OS integration" you mean "write special code for each platform" then the answer is no.

As you mentioned, you would like file system access, and background processing. That combination is not available in a cross-platform way at this moment.

If by "OS integration" you meant "without having to wait for apple/google/ms to provide the ability" then the answer is yes/maybe.

All the popular platforms have Push notifications and background processing support, as long as you code it the way each particular platform expects it.

But file system access will be limited to what restrictions the platform places on you. For instance in ios and win8(phone) there is no wy to write or read a file outside of your own apps private file structure. For security reasons, you cannot access the file system of other apps.

UPDATE:

The general pattern here is to release an app for every platform you want to support.
The app will register itself with its respective platform's push notification service.

You will write generic server side code to accept the data you want to push to all your client devices. Then you will invoke the respective push API's for each platform you support,  causing the client devices to wake up and trigger the app that you provided to respond.

When the app opens, you get the app to contact your server and download the full data "the push notification being just the wakeup call for your app"

This way you can easily tell how which of your devices have received the data.

Each platform specific app must save the data to its own local storage and provide a way for the data to be shared via the methods supported by its respective platform.

On IOS it can be as simple as supporting the "Open In.." paradigm.
On W8Phone, you'll have to publish the data via one of the available "sharing contracts"
And so forth for every platform you want to support.

This is the general pattern at the moment. There are some caveats. On IOS, the app will nt automatically start when a push notification is received. This means your app will only download the whole of the data when the app is opened by the user.

A mobile app also cannot generally run indefinitely in the background. This means that once the app is started, you have a limited window for push notifications to be automatically processed by your app. After the allowed "background time". The app will close and any push notifications beep on the device, but wont open the app until the user taps on one of the notifications or opens the app directly.

Comment: I'm talking for the second case. And how do I save files in OSes like WinPhone8,iOS without access to the filesystem?

Comment: You have access to a small part of the filesystem belonging to the app you control. You generally cannot write to directories in the filesystem belonging to other apps.

Comment: What about multiple apps? Sending unique data for each app from one service?

Answer (score 1):

Use [WebSocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) (with or without [socket.io](http://socket.io)).
In the future, you could use WebRTC.

With Websockets, the setup is really simple. The client (a user agent, like a browser or a WebView) connects to the Websocket server, over http(s) (less problems with firewalls) and that's it. There's a bidirectional socket with an event-based API.

Answer (score 1):

Technically you could use [XMPP Libraries](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/), it is meant for implementing chat system (msn, gtalk, facebook chat, etc...) but this could work well as a push message system because it is opensource and well built to handle all the cases you never thought of. Also you could host your own server and send push message that way...

Answer (score 1):

if you want to receive and send real time communication between a server and client (irrespective of the device or OS), i would highly recommend you use XMPP technology because it is designed for the sort of things you're asking for.

The Extensible Messaging and Presence Protocol (XMPP) is an application profile of the Extensible Markup Language [XML] that enables the near-real-time exchange of structured yet extensible data between any two or more network entities. The core features of XMPP defined in [XMPP‑CORE] provide the building blocks for many types of near-real-time applications, which can be layered on top of the core by sending application-specific data qualified by particular XML namespaces.

http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6121.html#intro - that is the latest RFC which will give you a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a webservice? In my previous project I used webservice to deliver data from mysql database. The webservice I used was nusoap. On the client side I used kSoap library for Android. Hope this helps.